# Does PHPUnit_Selenium Code Coverage Work?

Tags: selenium, phpunit, code-coverage

[In the PHPUnit docs](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/selenium.html), it says that it's possible to get code coverage data:

> PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase can collect code coverage information for tests run through Selenium:
>
> 1. Copy PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase/phpunit_coverage.php into your webserver's document root directory.
> 2. In your webserver's php.ini configuration file, configure PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase/prepend.php and PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase/append.php as the auto_prepend_file and auto_append_file, respectively.
> 3. In your test case class that extends PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase, use
>    protected $coverageScriptUrl = 'http://host/phpunit_coverage.php';
>    to configure the URL for the phpunit_coverage.php script.

I haven't been able to get this to output any coverage information. I am able to get code coverage info through normal unit tests.

For my app running at `http://localhost/ts2_templates/` I've copied `phpunit_coverage.php` to `http://localhost/phpunit_coverage.php`.

I've added the following to php.ini:

```
auto_prepend_file = "/path/to/pear/share/pear/PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase/prepend.php"
auto_append_file = "/path/to/pear/share/pear/PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase/append.php"
```

... and verified they are being called with a `die("yep it's me");`.

Finally, I added the following to my test case:

```
<?php

class WebTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
{
    # added line below
    protected $coverageScriptUrl = 'http://localhost/phpunit_coverage.php';

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->setBrowser('firefox');
        $this->setBrowserUrl('http://localhost/ts2_templates');
    }

    public function testTitle()
    {
        $this->url('http://localhost/ts2_templates');
        $this->assertContains('test', $this->title());
    }
}

?>
```

Here's the command for running the test with code coverage, generated by PHPStorm:

`/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/php -dxdebug.coverage_enable=1 /private/var/folders/pp/0t4y41f95j5313qm_f8b42fw0000gn/T/ide-phpunit.php --coverage-clover /path/to/coverage/ts2_templates$WebTest.coverage --no-configuration WebTest /Users/Ian/php/ts2_templates/tests/WebTest.php`

Heres the output of the coverage XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<coverage generated="1341015508">
    <project timestamp="1341015508">
        <metrics files="0" loc="0" ncloc="0" classes="0" methods="0" coveredmethods="0" conditionals="0" coveredconditionals="0" statements="0" coveredstatements="0" elements="0" coveredelements="0"/>
    </project>
</coverage>
```

The test itself passes.

I have verified there are no exit or die statements anywhere in the code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I also had some issues getting things to work. The following [post in the YII forum](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/31373-selenium-code-coverage-is-blank/page__p__165738#entry165738) by Samuel Goldstein helped me out:

> I ended up moving the prepend.php and append.php into my project's document root.
>
> I also found that the temporary file location made a difference - I originally was trying to save them to `/tmp/` and PHP was silently failing. When I changed `$GLOBALS['PHPUNIT_COVERAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY']` to `myroot/protected/runtime/tmp` and did a chmod 777 on that directory, it started working.
>
> One thing that might frustrate you a bit is that code run through Ajax does not get flagged as being covered.
>
> This appears to be a known problem with Selenium. Google "github sebastianbergmann phpunit-selenium issues" and track down [closed issue #22](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/issues/22) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely working. I have set up selenium tests in symfony measuring the coverage according to the documentation.

The biggest issue I had was, that the coverage data had the wrong path to the files in it, and therefore could not align the sources with the coverage data. This is because I executed tests from a different place, as the server kept the files in. Therefore I tweaked the `append.php` to rewrite the path to the place where my source files are.